# Unable update UILable using dispatch_async in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am setting json string value to UILabel using dispatch_async method. But Its unable to show updated value , but when I am printing label text, its showing updated value.
here is my code-

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.extract_json(data!)
                })

 func extract_json(jsonData:NSData)
{
    let json: AnyObject?
    do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
        print("full data \(json!)")
    } catch {
        json = nil
        return
    }
    let user_object = json!["opportunity_master"] as! NSArray
    let data_block = user_object[0] as? NSDictionary
    self.opp_title = (data_block!["opportunity_title"] as? String)!

        print(self.opp_title)

       <-- **here I am updating UILabel**-->

        self.Event_title.text = self.opp_title
        self.Event_title.setNeedsDisplay()

        print("event title label \(self.Event_title.text)")
}
```

**I am unable update values, Please suggest any other method to implement . Thank you**

Comment: If the below answers are not working, your label must be setting wrong frame or the string is empty, try set the label background color and make sure its there and showing with some random string

Comment: What function is your dispatch async call in?

Answer (score 0):

While you are updating the label text use this :-

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

self.Event_title.text = self.opp_title
self.Event_title.setNeedsDisplay()

})
```

Comment: Just give this a try and let me know self.Event_title.text = "\(self.opp_title)"

Comment: Please suggest me is there any other method to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , It should work.

```
self.extract_json(data!)

func extract_json(jsonData:NSData)
{
    let json: AnyObject?
    do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
        print("full data \(json!)")
    } catch {
        json = nil
        return
    }
    let user_object = json!["opportunity_master"] as! NSArray
    let data_block = user_object[0] as? NSDictionary
    self.opp_title = (data_block!["opportunity_title"] as? String)!

    print(self.opp_title)

        <-- **here I am updating UILabel**-->

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        self.Event_title.text = self.opp_title
        self.Event_title.setNeedsDisplay()

    })

    print("event title label \(self.Event_title.text)")
}
```

Comment: please suggest any other method to update UIlable..?